# Make a regex expression

Tags: regex

I want to make a regular expression to match several { curly } braces in a string.

The { text1 } is { text2 } and { if {xxx} else { xxx } }.

If I use { .* } it will match the first { and the last one } and all between is not matched separately.

I need this in order to block parts that do not need to me touched in this case { text1} {text2 } and { if {xxx} else { xxx } } but leave the words "the" "is" "and" unlocked.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what's being asked here. _But_ if you're only interested in matching "inner" curlies, consider `\{[*}]+\}`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to escape the curly braces as `\{` and `\}`.

Secondly, you need to use "reluctant quantifiers" rather than "greedy quantifiers". `.*` will match as many characters as it can, subject to the regular expression as a whole matching, while `.*?` will match as few characters as it can. so you want something like `\({.*?\})*`.

You originally tagged the question XML though there was no further mention of XML in the question. If this regular expression is for use in XML Schema (XSD), note that the XSD regex dialect does not support reluctant quantifiers. An alternative in this case (and probably a good idea anyway) is to replace `.` by `[^}]`, which matches everything except a closing brace.

If you want to analyse a string containing nested braces, then regular expressions aren't the right tool for the job: you need to write a parser.